# How to backup passwords from pass

Tags: linux, passwords

I have a lot of passwords saved using the `pass` command. But the problem is that I have to re-install Linux on my laptop so is there's anyway to backup the passwords from `pass` securely?

Comment: I believe that pass stores everything inside ~/.password-store

Comment: @Aroly7 but it's in encrypted text. And isn't it going to look for the GPG key before decrypting on the re-installed Linux?

Comment: @John but how do I copy all the passwords to that application? I have like 100 passwords.

Comment: Pass uses PGP by default so if you plan to transfer PGP keys it shouldn't be problem. Verify it by using gpg to try decrypt it.

Comment: If you can use gpg to verify that you can decrypt it. Then just copy the key and directory to your new install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution! The thing that we can do is first of all set up a github, gitlab, or whatever repo with `pass` password database. For that we'll have to install `pass-git-helper`, it's in the AUR if you're on Arch.
Then we'll set up a git repo:

```bash
pass git init
pass git remote add origin <url>
pass git add -A
pass git commit -m "initial commit"
pass git push -u origin master
```

This will push all passwords to git repo, make sure the git repo is private.

Now we'll back up the GPG key:

```bash
gpg --export-secret-keys $ID > my-private-key.asc
```

Copy the file `my-private-key.asc` to a USB drive or whatever storage device you have before wiping disk.

To restore the passwords again, copy the private key file to the new system and of course, don't forget the passphrase of GPG key and then run these commands:

```bash
gpg --import my-private-key.asc
git clone <url> ~/.password-store/
```

Thanks to @Aroly7 for giving me the path to solution.